# Testing equality of referencing rows

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have a number of tables that follow this rather common pattern: `A <-->> B`. I would like to find the pairs of matching rows in table *A* where certain columns have equal values and also have referencing rows in *B* where certain columns have equal values. In other words, a pair of rows *(R, S)* in *A* matches, iff for given sets of columns *{a<sub>1</sub>, a<sub>2</sub>, …, a<sub>n</sub>}* in *A* and *{b<sub>1</sub>, b<sub>2</sub>, …, b<sub>n</sub>}* in *B*:

- We have *R.a<sub>1</sub>* = *S.a<sub>1</sub>*, *R.a<sub>2</sub>* = *S.a<sub>2</sub>*, …, *R.a<sub>n</sub>* = *S.a<sub>n</sub>*.
- For every *R*'s referencing row *T* in *B* exists *S*'s referencing row *U* in *B* s.t. *T.b<sub>1</sub>* = *U.b<sub>1</sub>*, *T.b<sub>2</sub>* = *U.b<sub>2</sub>*, …, *T.b<sub>n</sub>* = *U.b<sub>n</sub>*.
- *(R, S)* matches iff *(S, R)* matches.

(I'm not very familiar with relational algebra, so my definition above might not follow any convention.)

The approach that I came up with was:

1. Find pairs *(R, S)* that have matching columns.
2. See if there's and equal number of (any) *R*'s and *S*'s referencing rows in *B*.
3. For each row in *B* find a matching row, group by the referencing row in *A* and count. Check that there are as many matching rows as referencing rows.

However, the query that I wrote (below) for steps 2 and 3, to find matching rows in *B*, is quite complex. Is there a better solution?

```
-- Tables similar to those that I have.
CREATE TABLE a (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    data TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE b (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    a_id INTEGER REFERENCES a (id),
    data TEXT
);

SELECT DISTINCT dup.lhs_parent_id, dup.rhs_parent_id
FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT
        MIN(lhs.a_id, rhs.a_id) AS lhs_parent_id, -- Normalize.
        MAX(lhs.a_id, rhs.a_id) AS rhs_parent_id,
        COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM b lhs
    INNER JOIN b rhs USING (data)
    WHERE NOT (lhs.id = rhs.id OR lhs.a_id = rhs.a_id) -- Remove self-matching rows and duplicate values with the same parent.
    GROUP BY lhs.a_id, rhs.a_id
) dup
INNER JOIN ( -- Check that lhs has the same number of rows.
    SELECT
        a_id AS parent_id,
        COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM b
    GROUP BY a_id
) lhs_ct ON (
    dup.lhs_parent_id = lhs_ct.parent_id AND
    dup.count = lhs_ct.count
)
INNER JOIN ( -- Check that rhs has the same number of rows.
    SELECT
        a_id AS parent_id,
        COUNT(*) AS count
    FROM b
    GROUP BY a_id
) rhs_ct ON (
    dup.rhs_parent_id = rhs_ct.parent_id AND 
    dup.count = rhs_ct.count
);

-- Test data.
-- Expected query result is three rows with values (1, 2), (1, 3) and (2, 3) for a_id,
-- since the first three rows (with values 'row 1', 'row 2' and 'row 3')
-- have referencing rows, each of which has a matching pair. The fourth row
-- ('row 3') only has one referencing row with the value 'foo', so it doesn't have a
-- pair for the referenced rows with the value 'bar'.
INSERT INTO a (id, data) VALUES
    (1, 'row 1'),
    (2, 'row 2'),
    (3, 'row 3'),
    (4, 'row 4');

INSERT INTO b (id, a_id, data) VALUES
    (1, 1, 'foo'),
    (2, 1, 'bar'),
    (3, 2, 'foo'),
    (4, 2, 'bar'),
    (5, 3, 'foo'),
    (6, 3, 'bar'),
    (7, 4, 'foo');
```

I'm using SQLite.

Comment: @tsnom . . . Could you rephrase your problem describing the data and the results you are looking for?  Relational algebra notation doesn't do a good job of explaining the problem (at least for me).

Comment: I don't have any at hand right now but I'll post some test data as soon as I get back home.

Comment: Done. Obviously not real-world but hopefully sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find matching and different rows it is easier to use INTERSECT and MINUS operations then joins...

But when only one field actually used in comparison JOIN solution looks better:

```sql
Select B1.A_Id, B2.A_Id
From (
    Select Data, A_Id, Count(Id) A_Count
    From B
    Group By Data, A_Id
) b1 
inner join (
    Select Data, A_Id, Count(Id) a_count
    From B Group By Data, A_Id
) b2 on b1.data = b2.data and b1.a_count = b2.a_count and b1.a_id <> b2.a_id
```

As I understand you need to find out the pairs of different a_id which have same data and count of data.

The result of my script gives, the possible couples in two directions, that left room for optimization on SQLlite specific syntax.

Result example:
{1,2}, {1,3}, {2,1}, {2,3}, {3,2}, {3,1}